# cannot identify Workbook as object variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building an automated request form and am running into a headache that only triggers for other users. 3 others receive a run-time error and I cannot figure out what is going on as I've used basically this same script in other books without ever having an issue reported.

```
    Sub tracker_upload()

ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

Run "processing" 'basic UF to display status

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Run "archive" 'saves completed form to a SP folder

With WaitForm
    .lbStatus.Caption = "...archiving form to shared drive"
    .Repaint
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

With Form
    If .Priority_Critical_YN = True Then
    p = "Critical"
    ElseIf .Priority_Must_Have_YN = True Then
    p = "High"
    ElseIf .Priority_Need_YN = True Then
    p = "Medium"
    ElseIf .Priority_Nice_YN = True Then
    p = "Low"
    End If
    .Shapes("upload").Visible = False
End With

With Range("tbData")
    uID = .Cells(1).Value
    .Cells(2) = "New"
    .Cells(3) = p
    .Cells(9) = Environ$("UserName")
    .Cells(10) = Date
    .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(1), ThisWorkbook.FullName, TextToDisplay:=uID
End With


With WaitForm
    .lbStatus.Caption = "...updating tracker information"
    .Repaint
End With


Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Requests Tracker")
'detect if workbook is already open and open if not
    If wb2 Is Nothing Then
    Application.Workbooks.Open ("My Shared Drive Location\Requests Tracker.xlsx"), ignorereadonlyrecommended = True
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Requests Tracker")
    End If
  On Error GoTo 0

wb1.Sheets("data").Range("tbData").Copy

With wb2
    .Activate
    With .Sheets("Requests")
        If .Range("tbTracker").Cells(1) = "" Then
        lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Else: lastrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If
    .Range("A" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
    .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    .Save
    .Close True
End With

Set wb2 = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0


With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
End With

Unload WaitForm

wb1.Save

mb = MsgBox("This request has been successfully recorded on the Tracker" & vbCrLf _
& vbCrLf _
& "The form will now close, would you like to open the tracker now?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "completed")

If mb = vbYes Then
    Application.Workbooks.Open ("My Shared Drive Location\Requests Tracker.xlsx"), ignorereadonlyrecommended = True
End If

If Application.Windows.Count = 1 Then
    wb1.Saved = True
    Application.Quit
Else: wb1.Close False
End If

End Sub
```

initially it was getting hung up on the `.Sheets("Requests")` line, then the line below it. It was the decimal in front of each, which I found really bizarre as I've never come across this before. Sure enough, after leaving the `.Save` and `.Close True` with decimals, it triggered another error on the next function preceded by a decimal as shown below.

**UPDATE:** I parsed out the bit of code where I set `wb1` and `wb2` as I identified it was `wb2` that was giving the user an error. I did some testing with several other users who had no issue setting & identifying `wb2` as `Workbooks("Requests Tracker")`. I finally got the sub to pass by adding the file extension to the end of the `Workbook` name. Why would this be required for this user only?

Comment: Please include your code rather than a screenshot of your code.

Comment: If you do not know that you are not supposed to post photos of your code, my guess is that you have also not made an attempt to browse this site for a potential solution...

Comment: @TylerH code added.

Comment: @urdearboy I have searched for the logic behind the sudden issues without luck, and as I said it's only just become and issue. It's never been an issue previously and continues to work flawlessly when I run the code.

Comment: @Davesexcel wb2 is an existing Workbook.

Comment: Do you have `wb2` set?

Comment: `It was the decimal in front of each, which I found really bizarre as I've never come across this before` - so you "fixed" the problem by making your code call the current worksheet/worksheet's `Activate` instead of `wb2.Activate`, and then you did not know how to fix `.Save`? Please put the `.` back, read about the [`With` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement), and make sure `wb2` is initialized.

Comment: Yes, wb2 is set. As I've said, the code runs flawlessly for me. I stepped thru each line with the user who continued to run into the run-time error and tested a few things to ensure wb2 was recognized; it was and `.Activate` was redundant. After numerous fails, the `.` was removed from `.Sheets` and the code would continue to the next line where it hung up on `.Range` it was removed again and then continued until reaching `.Save`.

Comment: The `decimal` here is from the `With` block. You say something like `With ThisWorkbook` and then before the `End With` you can say `.Sheets("some sheet").Activate`. Which is interpreted as `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("some sheet").activate`. Removing that `decimal` means you are acting on whatever is the `ActiveSheet` of the `ActiveWorkbook` which may not be what you want here.

Comment: In fact reading through your code it's 100% not what you want. That `.Save` is being applied inside the `With wb2` block. So that line is saying `wb2.save`. By taking that `decimal` off of there you are actually just saving the `ActiveWorkbook` which is almost definitely `wb1` at this point in the code execution because you commented out the `.Activate` just above. Not your intentions, I'm guessing.

Comment: It would advisable to take some time to understand why your code is erroring, and what it's doing before monkeying with it and causing even more issues.

Comment: Here's what's probably happening. Your `wb2` variable is set to `Set wb2 = Workbooks("Requests Tracker")` Do you have a workbook by that name open when this code executes? If you do... does it have a worksheet/tab named "Requests"? That block of code in your picture is trying to activate that workbook, find that "Requests" tab, find the last row in that tab, and paste whatever is in the clipboard. Then it's trying to save that workbook and close it. If that workbook isn't open when this code executes, or it doesn't have a tab with that name it will throw an error.

Comment: I say the `.Activate` is redundant because by opening "Requests Tracker" it becomes the `ActiveWorkbook`. I understand that I WANT the decimal there because my `With` block essentially says `wb2.Save` wb2.Close`. The issue here is, they are receiving errors on these lines and I have no idea why. I stated removing the decimals remove the errors for them, but this is definitely not the route I want to go.

Comment: @JNevill yes and yes. On the lines above where they are getting a run-time error, I check to see if "Requests Tracker" is open (which it never is), open it and then `set wb2 =`. The only `Worksheet` in that book is "Requests".

Comment: I just confirmed with two OTHER users that the sub runs just fine. It saves the completed form in an archive folder, opens the "Tracker"(wb2), transfers a few fields of info, saves and closes. Again I tested it with the problem users and added a `msgbox wb2.name` before the `With` block and they are getting the object or with block variable not set run-time error. I'm really at a loss. Should I have them try an Office repair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify `set wb2 = "Requests Tracker.xlsx"` in order for the user to not hit a run-time error. I do not know why `.xlsx` had to be added for **this one user and no one else** in the entire department...but that resolved the headache.